# How to create a "Done" or "Back" button in jqmobile to jump back to application from a pdf viewer?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am developing an application using jquery mobile and phonegap. I am displaying pdf files in the app stored on a server and passing the address to the a href link.

```
<a href="#popupMenus" data-rel="popup" data-role="button"  data-inline="true" data-transition="slideup" style="background: transparent; border: 0px; text-shadow: 0px;">



 </a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenus" data-theme="d">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="d">

                   <li><a href="http://noondigital.com/app-pdf/Gasoline%20Engine%20Oils/protec%20Green.pdf">Protec Green</a></li>

    </ul>

    </div>
```

The pdf is opening but there is no "done" button or "back" button that could allow me to go back to the app itself closing the pdf viewer.

Any Help would be most appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inAppBrowser plugin to open the PDF, inAppBrowser plugin has a close button.

Install the plugin

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Open pdf using

```
window.open(pdflink, '_blank');
```

And there will be a close button.